# If #REF! then reference another part of pivot table

Tags: excel, ref

I am using a PivotTable, and using the GETPIVOTDATA formula to populate
data on a separate worksheet. Some days there is no data for this particular pivot table column. Is there a way I can include with my GETPIVOTDATA statement, that if it shows an error
or #REF! it will reference another cell in that pivot table. I tried an If(And) statement and it did not work.
Here is the current formula`=GETPIVOTDATA("Disposition",'ACD Service Levels Pivot'!$A$3)-GETPIVOTDATA("Disposition",'ACD Service Levels Pivot'!$A$3,"Application","CallbackQueue")`

The reference cell I would like for error #REF! to go to is `GETPIVOTDATA("Disposition",'ACD Service Levels Pivot'!$A$3)`

Thank you

Comment: You can use iferror()

Comment: I tried ifefforr and it works for the first half of the formula. But I have more than one argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@usmanhaq Thank you for the comment. My goal was to make the formula logic dependent on the pivot table. However, I created a "helper table" using iferror. In which when the pivot table does not have the available data, the helper table will show "0". I can proceed with writing the formula to look at the helper tables "0" instead of the Pivot tables "#REF!" error it throws when no data is available using GETPIVOTDATA. Thanks for leading me down the path.